# I cannot import h5py, although installed

Tags: python, h5py

This seems to be a recurrent problem, and I've tried most of the fixes I found online, without success. So I am working with miniconda3, and following anaconda.org, I did:

`conda install -c anaconda h5py`

h5py does appear in the list when I type in my terminal `conda list`.

I'm on a Mac, with python version 3.9.5.

Running `import h5py` on PyCharm, I get "No module named 'h5py'" and on Jupiter Notebook, I get the following error message, perhaps indicating some conflicts with other libraries (I have installed/uninstalled h5py several times following different methods found online):

`````
Input In [3], in <module>
----> 1 import h5py

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:33, in <module>
     30     else:
     31         raise
---> 33 from . import version
     35 if version.hdf5_version_tuple != version.hdf5_built_version_tuple:
     36     _warn(("h5py is running against HDF5 {0} when it was built against {1}, "
     37            "this may cause problems").format(
     38             '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_version_tuple),
     39             '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)
     40     ))

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/version.py:15, in <module>
     10 """
     11     Versioning module for h5py.
     12 """
     14 from collections import namedtuple
---> 15 from . import h5 as _h5
     16 import sys
     17 import numpy

File h5py/h5.pyx:1, in init h5py.h5()

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/defs.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _H5Pget_fapl_ros3
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/defs.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: /Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/libhdf5.103.dylib
 in /Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/defs.cpython-39-darwin.so````
`````